# Which is more correct: input into the system or input onto the system?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm confused about the one to use, should I say

> The Lecturers are already on the system

or

> The Lecturers are already in the system

Comment: Not nearly enough info.  What is "the system"?  If it's a public address system they are **on** it.  If it's a computerized database of lecturers they are **in** it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly misleading as you refer to *input* in the title, but then ignore it is the body of the question.

Regardless, you can not use *on* with the verb *to input*, but use can use both *in* and *on* with the verb *to put*.

Therefore, you can

> put someone/something on to the system

or

> put someone/something into the system

Either is correct, and commonly used, although I would argue that *on* is more likely to be used in an informal sense or by non-technical people.

However, you can only

> input someone/something *in* to the system